# Is it possible to remove window by clicking button?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode4, nswindow

I am writing an app in which i want a `WelcomeWindow`.
`WelcomeWindow` contain some `Text` , `CheckBox Button` (with text- Don't want this message again) and one `Ok` button.

What i want is when my **CheckBox state is On** like `([checkBox state ]== NSOnState)` and if i press `Ok` button then this `WelcomeWindow` should be close and 
it won't be open again even if i `Quit` the app and then again `run` the app.
Is it possible in mac app ?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Of course. You need to save an info that your app did already pass the welcome window. For instance NSDefaults or Sqlite. It can be stored as a boolean value. Then you just ask for that value in the beginning to display or not display mentioned window.

Comment: Thanks Vanya..!! I use `NSUserDefaults` and its working fine..!!:)